# Email Form: $_POST is empty after form submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, post

I've been all over the forums. The general reason this doesn't work is that you need a NAME attribute, not an ID. I have a name attribute and I still get empty $_POST fields on submit. I'm a beginner and have been at this for 6 hours trying to figure it out. It's probablly something simple. Please help.

I got this free template off ShapeBootstrap: https://shapebootstrap.net/item/1524963-evento-free-music-event-template

My html:

```
<form action="sendemail.php" method="post" name="contact-form" class="contact-form" id="main-contact-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email ID">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" required class="form-control" rows="10" placeholder="Enter your message"></textarea>
    </div>                        
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Send</button>
    </div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
</form>
```

My php:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $status = array(
        'type'=>'success',
        'message'=>'Thank you for contact us. As early as possible we will contact you'
    );

    $name = ($_POST["name"]); 
    $email = ($_POST['email']); 
    $subject = "Website Message";
    $message = ($_POST['message']); 

    $email_from = $email;
    $email_to = 'adam.wilson45@yahoo.com';//replace with your email

    $body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

    $success = mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

    echo json_encode($status);
    die;
```

JavaScript:

```html
// Contact form validation
 var form = $('.contact-form');
 form.submit(function () {'use strict',
  $this = $(this);
  $.post($(this).attr('action'), function(data) {
   $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
  },'json');
  return false;
 });

 $( window ).resize(function() {
  menuToggle();
 });

 $('.main-nav ul').onePageNav({
  currentClass: 'active',
     changeHash: false,
     scrollSpeed: 900,
     scrollOffset: 0,
     scrollThreshold: 0.3,
     filter: ':not(.no-scroll)'
 });

});
```

Thank you so much in advanced!

Comment: What does `print_r($_POST);` show, nothing?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to header injection attacks. I suggest to use a mail library. Like [swift](http://swiftmailer.org/)

Comment: It's not a boolean expression, it doesn't affect the value

Comment: You're right Mihai, I checked here.  Then, I'd check    print_r($_POST) like chris85 suggested.  if it returns nothing, it means you are submitting your form to the wrong page

Comment: Move header('Content-type: application/json'); after mail()

Comment: Where is the code that submits the form? If you're returning JSON, you're presumably using AJAX.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. A little over my head so forgive me if I'm slow. I'm not sure how to check print_r($_POST) atm. Looking into that now.

Comment: Sounds like JavaScript.. do you have any of it to show us?

Comment: @putvande I do have a few errors in my javascript that dreamweaver is showing. How can I show you guys here in a readable format?

Comment: I added the js to the original post

Comment: Is it a lot? Post it in the question, or at least the bit where you setup and make the request. You could also post it inside a jsfiddle.net.

Comment: I should clarify that an email does send, however nothing the user inputs in the fields show.

Comment: @devpro Thanks, I changed it but it doesn't seem to change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't passing any data in your `$.post` script.
Change `$.post($(this).attr('action'), function(data) {` to `$.post($(this).attr('action'), form.serialize(), function(data) {`. The `form.serialize()` bit passes an object of your form data to the PHP script.

See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ for more info.

Answer (score -1):

THANK YOU @putvande ! Your answer pointed me in the right direction! Adding the form.serialize was close. We needed to add $this. right before it. I wish I talked to you 8hrs ago.
Answer:
Change

```html
$.post($(this).attr('action'), function(data) {
```

to

```html
$.post($(this).attr('action'), $this.serialize(), function(data) {
```